# How to pass TFS build variable to TFS email alert xsl file

Tags: xml, xslt, tfs, tfs-2015

I am trying to trigger customized email alerts after a build is complete. I have a set of test results stored in the build agent (hosted using IIS). I use TFS variables to store the path of the log results:

```
$(LogsPublishDirectory)\AppName_$(Build.BuildNumber)
```

I need to include, in the email, the information to access these logs (as a link) such as :

```
http://123.456.789.00:5555/AppName_$(Build.BuildNumber)
```

From the MSDN link(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552337(v=vs.120).aspx), I figured I need to modify the XSL file of the build job.

My question is:

1. How do I pass the TFS variables into the XSL file so that the logs link is generated dynamically?
2. Please give guidance on how to edit the XSL file as I have never done this before?

Answer (score 0):

**How to edit the xsl file?**

*First to perform these procedures, you must be a member of the **Administrators** security group on the Team Foundation application-tier server.*

1. Navigate to the file location `Drive:\%programfiles%\Microsoft Team
   Foundation Server 14.0\Application Tier\TFSJobAgent\Transforms\1033`
2. Find the related xsl file.You should make a backup copy of any files
   that you want to change, and then test your changes.
3. Open the .xsl file in a notepad or some other text editor. I choose VS to open the file.
4. Edit and save the file to show the message that you want in the notification email.

Here is the snippet of code to add a hyperlink to *Bing*.

```
  <xsl:call-template name="link">
    <xsl:with-param name="format" select="'html'"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="link" select="'http://www.bing.com'"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="displayText" select="'Bing'"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
```

[image]

The variable will not change to the correspond value in the XSL file and e-mail. A workaround could be subscribe to the **Event Service via TFS API** and create your own e-mails. It's probably more work than you need to though.

Check this blog for further information:[TFS 2012 API Create Alert Subscriptions](http://geekswithblogs.net/BobHardister/archive/2013/07/24/tfs-2012-api-create-alert-subscriptions.aspx). It applies to TFS2015 as well.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. That definitely answers how to edit the XSL file, but how do I pass TFS parameters to the XSL file. Is it even possible ? If not, what is your recommendation?

Comment: Afraid not, the variable will not change to the correspond value. A workaround could be subscribe to the Event Service via TFS API and create your own e-mails. It's probably more work than you need to though. Check this blog for further information:　http://geekswithblogs.net/BobHardister/archive/2013/07/24/tfs-2012-api-create-alert-subscriptions.aspx  It applies to TFS2015 as well

Comment: Will look into the API option and post my feedback

Comment: Patrick... So I tried the long way to use Event Service via TFS API. I was able to connect to TFS using TFSTeamProjectCollection but I am not able to access IEventService or DeliveryPreference using the TFS API. Do I need to access it by importing the .Net assembly into Java or is there a better way ?